# Instance variables with same name in different classes causing compile error

Tags: objective-c

I have two objc .m classes, we'll call them controller1.m and controller2.m. In both controller1.m and controller2.m I have instances of UIAlertController, something like this:

> controller1.m

```
@implementation controller1
    UIAlertController *alertController;
//more code
@end
```

> controller2.m

```
@implementaion controller2
    UIAlertController *alertController;
//more code
@end
```

When I try to build the project, I get the error

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And the error log looks like this

```
duplicate symbol _alertController in:
/Users/.../Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-cdtbqibmmbsosrdeyqughefeazaa/Build/Intermediates/AppName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/controller1.o
/Users/.../Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-cdtbqibmmbsosrdeyqughefeazaa/Build/Intermediates/AppName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/controller2.o
```

I changed the names of the instance variables for now and it worked... Why do I have to do this? Does Xcode realize that these variables are being used in the same way (due to their name), and that I should have them declared globally, somehow?

Comment: Declare them in the interface as properties.

Comment: @danh Ah, okay. But why is that? [Forgive me, I'm pretty new with objective-c]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that those variables are not instance variables. They are global variables.

To make them instance variables they need to be in the curly braces of the `@implementation` block as follows:

```
@implementation controller1 {
    UIAlertController *alertController;
}

//more code

@end
```

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. And is there a difference between doing it the way you have it versus the way @Danh recommended, by making it a property of the class?

Comment: My way fixes your declaration of the instance variable. Dan's way replaces the instance variable with a property. There are plenty of debates about whether you should use private properties or instance variables. Either approach works.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It looks like I have to read up on the difference between instance variables and properties. So far it looks like they are accessed differently and thats about it

Answer (score 1):

As you have it, the code declares a global with the same name in each module.  To make the pointers private to their respective classes, use properties...

```
// controller1.m

@interface controller1 ()

@property(strong,nonatomic) UIAlertController *alertController;
// any other property private to controller1

@end

@implementation controller1

// only methods here

@end
```

Comment: You do not need to change them to properties to fix them properly.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a difference in what you are recommending versus what @rmaddy recommended/why did you recommend that? I accepted rmaddy's answer because his answers appeared slightly before yours. I do see that you commented on my question before him though

Comment: sure.  the difference is that I'm suggesting a little more modern declaration that, under the covers, creates a getter and a setter method for you.  So you can say `self.alertController`or `self.alertController = // blah`.

Comment: Hmm thats interesting. So I'm guessing that @properties take up more memory (not that it matters for the small scale apps I build), and should be used when I have setting/getting them in mind? Whereas I should make an ivar if I don't need that stuff for it?

Comment: They are the same data-wise.  The object gets two more methods that I would argue are a net benefit.